# threshold plan ahead approaches

Tags: 2010, list, list-view-threshold, capacity-planning

I would like to ask which are the approaches being used to plan list implementation taking scalability into account.

I know that we can create indexes, subfolders, multiple views and so on, but that is kind of thinking in a post-implementation scenario.

In other words, if we know beforehand that a list will easily reach thousands of items, what is a general best practice?

Particularly, does it make sense to create an automated procedure that provisions a new list when it reaches X number of items? I say this because according to "[Designing large lists and maximizing list performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813%28v=office.14%29.aspx)" we should use a single list scenario when `It is not logical to place items in separate lists`.
So if it makes sense, but the data will reach the threshold in a few months, how can we best plan ahead? Is it acceptable to let the list grow large but just have a good filtering and indexing mechanism?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft states in it's [Software boundaries and limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx#ListLibrary) Technet article, 30 millions items are supported per list.

So it's ok to keep a list that large if you have default filtered views and proper indexing.
But I suggest to be aware of other issues related to the lists with so many items. For example, there is [known performance issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2420771) in SharePoint 2007 and 2010 when there are too many unique permissions assigned to the list items. I don't know if it's fixed in 2013 or 2016, though. But you can easily hit this in if you run a workflow against this list which assigns unique per-item permissions.

My personal approach is to avoid such lists that can grow so large.